# How to generate unique LIKES id in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a button in my page:

```
if($posts = $q->fetchAll()) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $username = $post[0];
        $post_id = $post[2];
        $status = $post[1];
        echo $username . " " . $status . "<br/>";
        echo "<button value = '$post_id' id = 'like' class='like' type='submit'>Like</button>";
    }
}
```

Let's assume I have ten result from the query, I will definitely have 10 LIKE button with the same ID.

Now my jQuery is coming this way:

```
$("#like").click(function() {  
    var menuId = $(this).val();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "likes.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id : menuId },
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
        $(".likecount").html( msg ); 
    });
});
```

Every click on a single button applies to all 10 buttons. How do I differentiate them and have the database affected accordingly?

Comment: Your buttons all have the same `id`; you need to give them different ID numbers inside the loop when you're generating them, and just file the click function for the one that is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're adding *like* elements via ajax, but you're binding the event handler to whichever like element is already part of the dom at any given moment:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //when dom is loaded, #like is selected, and event is bound
    $('#like').click(function(){});
});
```

inside the click handler, you perform an ajax call that may add another like element to the page, but you *never* bind an event handler to that new element.
You have 2 options: add an event handler for each element that is added to the page dynamically (not so good, bad for performance). *OR* ***delegate*** the event. As an added bonus, you don't need the ID's of the like buttons anymore. You can use the like class to delegate!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('body').on('click', '.like', function()
    {
        //handle click on like button here
    });
});
```

This adds an event listener to the body tag, that will call the callback function whenever a click is registered on an element that has the `like` class.

I'll edit this response, to give you a, purely hypothetical way to ensure unique like id's

---

Using a closure, you can easily get unique ID's, by exploiting the fact that closure vars can outlive the closure function. But as you can see, just from the verbosity and added complexity of the code below, this approach is *not* to be recommended. Simply use the class, and leave the ID out. *delegation all the way*!

```
$('body').on('click', '.like', (function(count)
{//closure, pass like buttons currently on page
    var idNum = 0;
    count.each(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + idNum);
        ++idNum;//increment
    });
    return function()
    {//this is the actual callback
         request.done(function( msg )
         {
             var chunk = $(msg);//parse HTML response
             chunk.find('.like').each(function()
             {
                 $(this).attr('id', ($(this).attr('id') || 'like') + idNum);
                 ++idNum;
             });
         });
    };
}($('.like'))));
```

Or, if for some reason you don't want to delegate the event:

```
$('.like').on(function handler()
{//callback should be named, you'll see why
    request.done(function( msg )
    {
        $('.like').off('click', handler);//remove handler
        //add msg to DOM
        $('.like').on('click', handler);//add handler, now including new DOM elements
    });
});
```

You could (and IMO should) optimize this further, by storing the `$.each` callback in a closure reference, too:

```
$('body').on('click', '.like', (function(count)
{//closure, pass like buttons currently on page
    var idNum = 0, eachCallback = function()
    {
        $(this).attr('id', ($(this).attr('id') || 'like') + idNum);
        ++idNum;//increment
    };
    count.each(eachCallback);
    return function()
    {//this is the actual callback
         request.done(function( msg )
         {
             var chunk = $(msg);//parse HTML response
             chunk.find('.like').each(eachCallback);
         });
    };
}($('.like'))));
```

This way, you avoid creating a callback function object on each click event... but read up on closures to fully understand why this is a better approach, performance wise.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not change your PHP to:

```
if($posts = $q->fetchAll()){
   foreach ($posts as $post){
   $username = $post[0];
   $post_id = $post[2];
   $status = $post[1];
     echo $username . " " . $status . "<br/>";
     echo "<button value = '$post_id' id = 'like_$post_id' class='like' type='submit'>Like</button>";
}
```

As each item relates to a post with a (I hope) unique ID, why not just append that value to the id property?

ID values **MUST BE UNIQUE**

Then you'll need to change your jQuery selector, how about:

```
$("button.like").click(function()
```

Comment: How will I then call the ID with jQuery?

Comment: Edited the response for you :)

Comment: Thank you but I don't quite get how `id = 'like_$post_id'` will work and how it is related to `$("button.like").click(function()`

Comment: You may be at cross purposes here. If the only reason you're giving buttons id values is for your jquery selector- you dont need them to have id's, you can just use  `button.like`...which selects all buttons with the css class 'like'.

Comment: I think the simpler solution would be to select the class of the button, instead of selecting the id. Parsing the DOM is expensive in jQuery, and now you're proposing to parse the DOM dynamically. Unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @AlanChavez read the last part of the above- the class IS being used as the selector...

Comment: Nope, I want each click on any should independent of the other.

Comment: The way you're binding the click handler won't work for like buttons that are added after the ajax call, you need to delegate the click event, as I explain in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ID as selectors in your jquery, use class selector if your buttons are going to use the same class.

For example:

```
if($posts = $q->fetchAll()){
   foreach ($posts as $post){
       $username = $post[0];
       $post_id = $post[2];
       $status = $post[1];
       echo $username . " " . $status . "<br/>";
       // Removing Id like, because Id should be unique in DOM.
       echo "<button value = '. $post_id. ' class='like' type='submit'>Like</button>";
    }
}
```

Your jQuery will look like:

```
// class selector is a dot (.), if you use an id selector (hashtag #) and you
// you have more than 1 element with that Id, jQuery will only select the first one.
  $('body').on('click', '.like', function(){ 
     var menuId = $(this).val();

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "likes.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { id : menuId },
      dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
      $(".likecount").html( msg ); 
    });
  });
```

Comment: `$('.like').click` won't handle the click events for the like buttons that the ajax calls return. the event handlers are bound on DOM ready, everything that gets added to the DOM tree afterwards won't work

Comment: Take Facebook, for example... I want something of that nature. When the LIKE button of a post is clicked, it should respond appropriately but won't $(".like").click(function(){ } affect the 10 buttons?

Comment: @user3009875, not necessarily. That's why you're using $(this).val() so that you're only getting the value of the element you just clicked. Edited my answer per Elias suggestion.